# Recyclerview GridLayoutManager scrollToPositionWithOffset not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Hi I am using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager to load images but its scrollToPositionWithOffset() method is not working.

I have saved recyclerview first visible item position in onSavedInstanceState() and I retrieve its value in onViewStateRestored() and I am getting correct positions everytime but RecyclerView doesn't scroll to desired position.I am checking that by rotating my screen but its not getting scrolled to desired position.

Here's my code:

```
  @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("position", ((GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition());
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        int state = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
        ((GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(state, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: just use recyclerviewObject.scrollToPosition(state);

Comment: Thanks !! but Not working :(

Comment: what is happening?

Comment: It just remains at position 0 when I rotate my device

Comment: did onViewStateRestored called?

Comment: Yes I debugged everything runs but it just doesn't scroll

Comment: This snippet will help you try recyclerChatView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            recyclerChatView.scrollToPosition(state );
                        }
                    }, 100);

Comment: Thanks that worked I tried with 200 :)

Comment: Welcome...! its fine its up to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use `smoothScrollToPosition()` instead of `scrollToPositionWithOffset()`

**Try this:**

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        int state = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(state);
    }
}
```